# inode and dentry relation confusion in VFS(virtual file system), where is the mapping between filename and inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory-structure, inode, vfs

There are many explanations and book sections regarding Linux's Virtual File System including here in SOF.
But I'm still a bit confused regarding the relation between *struct dentry* and *struct inode* and a mapping between a filename and an Inode.

I thought that dentry is the way of the filesystem to locate the inode, but also it says in every reference that I read that the dentry object is in-memory, so once you restart the machine, how can you locate a newly created file?

So when you create a file with path */a/b/c* and then you want to open this file, how does the filesystem locate it? if you could refer both to dentry and Inode objects in your answer

Answer (score 2):

A filesystem consists of two major blocks of behavior:

- The on-disk format, the way stored data is represented on persistent media.
- The synchronization among processes, kernel code, and hardware when accessing stored data.

A filesystem like FAT32 has an on-disk format that can be read in Windows, Mac, and Linux - the on-disk format stays the same, but the synchronization and access part varies across operating systems.

On-disk formats of filesystems like UFS and ext3, and indeed most Unix-bred filesystems define the concepts of "inode" and "dentry". FAT32 and SMB do not.

Still, Linux, and other kernels, found it extremely useful to have common code across different on-disk formats, so the VFS abstraction layer was created. This abstraction layer exists only in memory; it does not dictate to the individual filesystems anything about the on-disk format.

However, the VFS' abstraction (an API that individual filesystems need to implement) defines data structures such as `struct inode` and `struct dentry` - but they only exist in memory.

ext4, for example, has a rather direct mapping between in-memory inodes & dentries to on-disk inodes & dentries. It has corresponding `struct ext4_inode` (stored in `i_private`) and `struct ext4_dir_entry` (stored in `d_fsdata`).

So on ext4, looking up `/a/b/c` is done by:

- Getting the root `struct inode`, which is already cached in VFS at mount time
- Asking ext4 to load `a` from that inode.
- The inode's content is a list (well, probably a more sophisticated data structure) of `ext4_dir_entry`s - ext4 will find the correct one
- ext4 will look at the `ext4_dir_entry`'s inode number and load the `ext4_inode` into a `struct inode` in the VFS cache.
- Using the cached `struct inode` and the `ext4_dir_entry`, ext4 will build a `struct dentry` and return it to the VFS.
- VFS will look at the dentry's inode, and ask ext4 to load `b` from it.
- The process repeats.

Note that the VFS' abstraction does not correspond 100% to ext4:

- `struct dentry` doesn't contain an inode number - the inode must be loaded
- `struct dentry` caches the type of the inode, whereas `ext4_dir_entry` does not.
- `struct dentry` can be *negative*, meaning it caches the fact that the file does NOT exist, so that if you run `ls x; ls x` and `x` doesn't exist, you don't go to disk the second time.